# Sending Generic Content-Type in Servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I am trying to relay some `ByteString` back to the client (browser). The client will not know the content-type of the document being requested so I am trying to send appropriate content-type response back to the client.  The document could be an image or pdf or word document, etc.

For example, the client will request `/document?id=55` and the server will respond with the appropriate content-type and the associated `ByteString`.

I followed the example [here](http://haskell-servant.github.io/tutorial/server.html#using-content-types-with-your-data-types): and I created something for an image.

```
 data IMAGE

 instance Accept IMAGE where
     contentType _ = "image" M.// "jpeg"

 instance MimeRender IMAGE LBS.ByteString where
     mimeRender _ = id
```

The challenge is the client will not be sending the request with some specific `Accept:` header so there is no way for me to react with an appropriate Mime Type like it is done [here](https://haskell-servant.github.io/posts/2015-08-05-content-types.html). Plus the above will only work for images (assuming browsers will infer a `png` even I send back `jpeg`) but not for `pdf`, `docx`,etc.

I thought about a paramaterized type like `MyDynamicContent String` and I will pass in the content type at run-time but I am not sure how I will declare my API i.e., what will I use instead of `'[JSON]`. Not sure such thing is even possible as the examples are just a simple datatype.

So my question is, if I want to send some `ByteString` as a response and set the `Content-Type` header dynamically, what will be the best way to do it using `servant`

**Update:** I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/400)

Comment: How does the server decide what content-type to respond with? (In particular, just to make sure, this cannot be statically determined?)

Comment: @user2141650: The `server` gets this info from the datastore (a document store service). It makes a call to the service and the service responds with the content-type and also the byte string. I know I can create an end point for each content-type (or mostly used ones at least) and send the content-type first and then ask the client to use the end point corresponding to the content-type. This is such a bad hack,moving a lot of this logic to the client, i feel it should be better handled by the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but a bit of a hack:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
module DynCT where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import Servant
import Servant.API.ContentTypes
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp

data WithCT = WithCT { header ::  ByteString, content :: ByteString }

instance AllCTRender xs WithCT where
  handleAcceptH _ _ (WithCT h c) = Just (h, c)

type API = Get '[] WithCT

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

server :: Server API
server = return $ WithCT { header = "example", content = "somecontent" }

main :: IO ()
main = run 8000 $ serve api server
```

Testing it:

```
  % curl localhost:8000 -v
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
< Content-Type: example
<
...
somecontent%
```

The idea is just to override the normal behaviour by declaring an overlapping instance for `AllCTRender`. Note that you'll probably also have to do some extra leg work for `servant-client`, `servant-docs` etc. if you're also using those. Given that, you may want to open an issue in the repo about this for more complete support.

Comment: Thank you so much. This indeed works. I am using `servant-docs` and I am getting type errors.  You already knew this will be an issue. Not sure what I need to provide to satisfy docs for using `'[]`. The error I get is `Could not deduce (Servant.API.ContentTypes.IsNonEmpty '[]) arising from a use of ‘Doc.docs’`.   I will open an issue and see if there is a clean way to solve the docs issue.

Comment: I made it work with the docs. Instead of using `'[]` I just used a generic custom mime type.  The Accept instance's content-type is getting overriden by the `AllCTRender` so that works out well. This way I am able to use the docs and return a custom mime type.

Comment: It seems like this no longer works in servant 0.15, because it is always failing with status 406.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now this hack works

```
data WithCT = WithCT {header :: BS.ByteString, content :: BS.ByteString}

instance AllCTRender '[IMAGE] WithCT where
  handleAcceptH _ _ (WithCT h c) = Just (fromStrict h, fromStrict c)

data IMAGE deriving (Typeable)

instance MimeRender IMAGE BS.ByteString where
  mimeRender _ content = fromStrict content

instance Accept IMAGE where
  contentType _ = ""

type ImageApi = Capture "image_id" ImageId :> Get '[IMAGE] WithCT
```